# Timing an img src from API to load with text in React

Tags: html, reactjs, axios

I've been getting back into React and front end development lately, but for the life of me I can't remember ever running into "slower" image load times.

I'm using an API to get some data back using Axios in React, and the API will send back an image link which will subsequently be used as the src for an image component. Currently the request is sent inside of a useEffect() on component render, and the link is stored using hooks as seen on the setImage() portion.

```
axios
        .get(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("Data received.");

            setName(res.data.drinks[0].strDrink);
            setImage(`${res.data.drinks[0].strDrinkThumb}/preview`);
            const drinkIngredients = [];
            const drinkMeasurements = [];
            for(let prop in res.data.drinks[0]) {
                if(prop.startsWith("strIngredient") && res.data.drinks[0][prop]) {
                    drinkIngredients.push(res.data.drinks[0][prop]);
                } else if(prop.startsWith("strMeasure") && res.data.drinks[0][prop]) {
                    drinkMeasurements.push(res.data.drinks[0][prop]);
                }
                if(prop === "strInstructions") {
                    // Since the instructions are one big string, assign it once in the for loop.
                    setInstructions(res.data.drinks[0][prop]);
                }
            }

            setIngredients(drinkIngredients);
            setMeasurements(drinkMeasurements);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

However, to my understanding, the image component has to assign the link and then make an additional request to retrieve and load that photo (I've attached a screenshot of the Network tab, random.php is the API request and preview is loading of the image).

My question is is there a way to make it so the text from the random.php request and image to load at the same time? I've looked into Suspense, but to my understanding the data from the API is coming back at once so I can't suspend rendering. Thanks!

[Screenshot of Network requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haVyC.png)

Comment: You can't load them in parallel because you don't know the image URL until you get a response from `random.php`. I would recommend using a local placeholder image initially

Comment: @Phil Hmm that's what I figured. Thanks for the placeholder recommendation, never thought to do that!